# How to detect water on google maps

Tags: google-maps, gps, maps

Is it possible to determine if a gps point is in water or near(not including elevation) . From what I have seen it doesn't seem possible. I had an idea of somehow getting the gps fence of water bodies and checking if the point lays in the fence. Sounds good but I can't find gps coordinate fences. If any one have any other ideas or a place to get those fences it would be great.

Comment: If the point is underwater at high tide and above water at low tide, does it count as "in water"?

Comment: Similarly, if the point is in a river which dried out in winter, does it count as "in water"? Or, if the latitude and longitude indicates that it is in a lake on the map, but the altitude of the point is 2 meters above the water level which is 1.5 meters above sea level, does it count as "in water"? I suggest you to "[edit]" your question and clarify.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I misunderstood your question. Are you looking for a Google API that checks if a latitude / longitude is defined as water in Google Maps?

Comment: I am trying to find away if given a gps coordinate is it "in a water body" or the shoreline. Not including elevation .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Verify if a point is Land or Water in Google Maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644452/verify-if-a-point-is-land-or-water-in-google-maps)

Comment: possible duplicate of [I need to know the predefined point is in the sea or on the land](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645649/i-need-to-know-the-predefined-point-is-in-the-sea-or-on-the-land)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the GPS fence for water from OpenStreetMap.
Then you do a point in polygon operation, optionally you put all polygons in
 a spatial search structure, like a quad tree, for a fast polygon search nearby the lat,lon point.

You can start [here](https://osmdata.openstreetmap.de/data/water-polygons.html). and later read more how to identify water in OpenStreetMap

A solution that works on small areas of waters, worldwide, would use much storage space If you concentrate on some countries this should work.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the article is a very interesting [approach](http://tech.bellycard.com/blog/where-d-the-water-go-google-maps-water-pixel-detection-with-canvas/).

Using google static maps to draw just some pixels around your coordinates, and then check whether its blue or not blue.

You can set a custom unique colour for "water" as a parameter to the google static map, which makes it easy for you to determine if it matches water or not